# Why doesn't a magnet have an angular motion?

Tags: angular-momentum, electrons, quantum-spin, crystals, ferromagnetism

It is said that a magnetic moment is always associated with angular momentum. For a particle, the magnetic moment $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and angular momentum $\boldsymbol{l}$ are related by

$\boldsymbol{\mu}=\gamma \:\boldsymbol{l}$

where $\gamma$ is the gyromagnetic ratio. In the Einstein-de Haas experiment, the rotation induced by magnetic moments is observed in a macroscopic sample (a rod).

So shouldn't a ferromagnetic sample be always rotating?

Comment: What is $\vec{L}$ the angular momentum of? The magnet? The electrons inside the magnet?.....?

Comment: You answered your own question.

Comment: @N.Steinle Thanks, I tried to explain my question better.

Comment: @my2cts You mean the difference between a particle and a macroscopic sample?

Note that in the Einstein-de Haas effect, the system is macroscopic.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The magnetic moment could be the sum of that from many small rotating or revolving charges. Then the magnet as a whole doesn't have to rotate.

It could be atoms spinning inside crystals. It could be electrons spinning around atomic nuclei. It could be electrons spinning like tops.

We can make up lots of stories to explain it. I'm not clear how to tell whether any of the stories are right. There might be some sort of data that one story fits better, and if no one story fits very well we might try combinations of them, and figure that it's 85% electrons spinning like tops, and 10% electrons on average orbiting around nuclei in probabilistic patterns which are unpredictable and indeterminate but which still have a certain reality, and 4% atoms spinning, and 1% something else. (I made up those numbers, with actual data we could fit better numbers to it.)

Comment: This is an unphysical answer as physics is not about "making up stories".

Comment: Some people believe that physics should not be about making up stories. But in fact a lot of it is.

Consider for example the various explanations of quantum theory, the Copenhagen explanation etc. These are stories. There is no data from experiments that gives any indication which of them are correct, or whether it means anything for one of them to be correct. It's only stories that people hope will make sense of things which don't make sense as sheer math.

Comment: I see your point, but magnetism is very well understood. No multiple interpretations there. All there is left to explain is the magnetic moment and spin of the electron.

Comment: Spin of electron is a story intended to explain stuff. Previously we had the story that electrons orbit a nucleus, and the nucleus itself might be spinning, and that explained the magnetic moment. 

But that story was discredited. A pair of electrons cannot orbit a nucleus, because they would inevitably radiate and lose energy and fall into the nucleus. It cannot happen, therefore they cannot provide a magnetic moment. So the entire moment must be provided by electrons that have intrinsic moment which does not make them fall into anything. It's the only story left.

Comment: That is not physics. It is your wholly unfounded opinion.

Comment: You could take the interpretation that physics is the math which describes what happens. QM, quantum electrodynamics, etc.

But all the interpretations which try to make pictures of things -- Feynman diagrams, explanations of QM, QED, etc -- are stories and not physics.

I could agree with that.

In that context, explaining the magnetic moment and spin of the electron is not physics but interpretation. Stories about physics, interpretations of physics, etc are not physics but at best are opinions.

I wouldn't disgree with that opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A permanent magnet actually has angular momentum. As it is *electron* angular momentum, mostly spin, the crystal itself does not rotate. A iron magnet, for example, has 5/2h of spin angular moment per iron atom. For 1 mole of iron it is 10$^{-9}$ Nms of AM. If the magnetic order disappears this will be converted into crystal AM. This is a small amount but perhaps measurable.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? If you were to suspend magnet and heat it up past Curie temperature, would it start spinning to compensate angular momentum lost due to collapse of spontaneous magnetisation?

Comment: Edited my answer.